# Using ImageView as background for an Android Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-xml, android-background

I want to take advantage of the scaleType property, which I cannot use if I set my image using the background property on the `LinearLayout`. I've tried using a `LinearLayout` with 2 children: the first is an `ImageView` (for the background image) and the second child is another `LinearLayout` containing `TextViews`, Buttons, etc. But the result is just the image followed by the other views.

Is it possible to float the nested `LinearLayout` over the `ImageView` somehow? I know that there's lots of variations on this question around, but I haven't found anything that's helped me yet. If I've missed something, please point me in that direction. Also, I'd like to do this in XML if possible, and I'm flexible about what type of layout I can use (it doesn't have to Linear).

Comment: As well as trying the answer from Rick Falck, you may want to look at this blog post http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I did it thusly using a RelativeLayout as the parent:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <ImageView
        style="@style/BackGroundImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!--Rest of widgets......-->

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Style for it:

```
<style name="BackGroundImageView">
    <item name="android:alpha">0.5</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">fitXY</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/img_background</item>
</style>
```

I used a style, because the alpha setting doesn't work on lower APIs (can't remember what the limit is offhand).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot use above because of I have adapter and images are set from their to display in `GridView`. So, in 2019 Im doing like below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <your_package_name.directory.SquareImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/gridImageView"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingStart="6dp"
        android:paddingEnd="6dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_image_holder_text"
        android:alpha=".85"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The key attribute for Stacking view here is `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`.

Also note that I created `android:background="@drawable/shape_image_holder_text"` to get some corner radius around my text view with some backdrop. Here is that xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#22000000" />
            <stroke
                android:color="#33000000"
                android:alpha="0.6"
                android:width="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="12dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

To make my image adjust to height and width to same size in GridView. I created a custom class for `SquareImageView`(You can use default `ImageView` if you are not using `GridView` or if you don't care about this).

My SquareImageView.java file:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class SquareImageView extends AppCompatImageView {

    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        //noinspection SuspiciousNameCombination
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

It look like this:

[image]